# How can I add controllers and some processing in the view page in the cms?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For instance in cms I create a page called "Account Details". For this logically I need a controller that would receive and process the request. The processing includes validation, db retrieval, etc. In the view part, I need a set of text boxes, etc. As I know, in cms I cannot create something like this. How to proceed in this way?